# How can I create a GTK combobox with no relief?

Tags: combobox, gtk, gtkmm

I know you can remove a button's relief with

```
button.set_relief(Gtk::RELIEF_NONE);   // gtkmm
```

Or

```
gtk_button_set_relief(button, GTK_RELIEF_NONE);   // gtk
```

But there's no corresponding method for a combobox.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can do this by adding a [GtkCssProvider](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html) and then customize your border and box-shadow with CSS.